# Counting problems that still remains unsolved?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I just proved that the cartesian product of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ is countable and I started to wonder if there exists any sets that is still not yet proven to be countable/uncountable?

Also, I counted this set in a similar way as you normally will count $\mathbb{Q}$. Does there exist any other 'fancy' techniques to count sets...? (Or could anyone recommend some literature on counting of sets, if it exists?)

Comment: maybe you find this interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis